# how can I edit TCP protocol (tcp.cc)

Tags: tcp, protocols, ns2, cc, end-to-end

My research is about minimizing End to End retransmission delay by touching Transport Layer Process to Process communication.

I did some changes to tcp.cc , changed window size. the changes i am doing are not affecting. ex: even if i removed tcp.cc file from NS2 folder but TCP topologies are still working, why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network protocol simulation, not programming.

Comment: sorry for the delay, this is about protocol simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you made any changes in .cc files then you have to run `make` command in your NS2.xx folder.

Comment: Thanks. :)
first i have to 'clean make' then 'make'

Comment: Naveen.S please contact me.
shankaultimate@gmail.com